# Can't build streamer tutorial for android on mac

Tags: android, macos, gstreamer

Can't build streamer tutorial_3 for android on mac
I,ve got all environment variables needed.
My eclipse can't to resolve some symbols, but to some of them i can get by pushing F3. It's very strange for me.[image]

Here is the command line output:

```
23:04:06 **** Build of configuration Default for project Tutorial3 ****  
/Users/antonivanuskin/android-develop/android-ndk-r10/ndk-build all 
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build-armeabi/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build-armeabi/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build-armeabi/libgstreamer_android.so
lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream generated with LTO version 2.2 instead of the     expected 3.0
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: /Users/antonivanuskin/android-develop/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm- linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc returned 1 exit status
/Users/antonivanuskin/android-develop/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [buildsharedlibrary_armeabi] Error 1

23:04:10 Build Finished (took 3s.740ms)*
```

I use ndk-10r and gst-1.4.0.
I know that there is no interfaces/xoverlay in new streamer.

**EDIT**

I've built ok, but steel got underlines of many glib-types and GST-macross. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

what is interesting that i have no underlined headers, for example: i've include pthread.h but have got underlined pthread_t and phtread_key_t....

i think that i have not install some general libraries on my mac, something like libc or what ever...may it couse this problem? The problem is that i can't run my app from eclipse. and for more: i use DS-5 CE IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because we build the android 1.4.x cerbero packages with the r9d NDK.

You might want to use the r9d NDK until we provide binaries built with a more recent NDK (started some builds to see if everything goes through fine).

Comment: on picture above you can see more details

Comment: Thanks with ndk version, but i still got a problem with underlines and unresolved symbols... pay attention to TYPES of data: GMainLoop, GMainContext,...,pthread_t, etc.... To definitions of some underlined symbols i even can get by pressing F3...confuse